# How to properly deal with a deallocated delegate of a queued nsoperation

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsoperation, delegation, nsoperationqueue

In my current project, several view controllers (like `vc`) spawn NSOperation objects (like `operation`) that are executed on a static NSOperationQueue. While the operation is waiting or running, it will report back to the view controller via delegation (`operation.delegate = vc`, assigned not retained).

These operations can take a while though, and in the mean time the app can dealloc the view controller (by popping them of a navigation controller's stack).

So far everything is intentional. The class containing the static NSOperationQueue has a way to get back at the operations, therefore the view controllers do not retain them. They're just alloc/init/autoreleased and put on the queue.

Now this also causes the problem. After the view controller deallocates, any calls to the NSOperation's spirited delegate will cause a bad access violation. From what I understand, it is not possible to check whether an object at a pointer has been deallocated, [as stated in this question](/questions/2954261/).

One fix I can think of is retaining the operation and setting the operation.delegate to nil on dealloc. But that'd be my least popular fix, for it would introduce a lot of extra ivars/properties to keep track of.

My question therefore is, are there other ways to work around this problem and if so, could you sketch one here?

Cheers,
EP.

**SOLUTION**: The approach that worked out best for me was a slight variation to Guiliano's answer:

- Implementing every delegate protocol in the queue manager is not feasible (20+ different protocols with 50+ methods), so I kept the direct delegate assignments. What I did change was the class making the assign call. This used to be the class (and delegate) that created the request, but now it is offloaded to the queue manager.
- The queue manager, next to assigning the delegate to the operation, also holds a secondary mutable dictionary to keep track of the delegate/operation pairs.
- Every delegate instance calls a `[QueueManager invalidateDelegate:self]` method on deallocation, which then looks up the request that belonged to the delegate and nils it. The dictionary operation/delegate pair is then also deleted to allow proper deallocation of the operation.
- Lastly with KVO observing the `isFinished` property of each operation, the mutable dict is kept clean, to make sure that all operation retain counts actually deallocate after they're finished.

Thanks Guiliano for providing the hint to using KVO for cracking this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to review your architecture and move the delegate to the class (assume QueueManager) that manages the queue instead of having a delegate in each operation:

- Create a QueueManagerDelegate that
  implements the method(s) you need to
  notify the viewControllers
- In QueueManager add a KVO observer for the isFinished property of each NSOperation (do this before adding the operation to the queue ;))
- In the callback of the KVO call the delegate method(s) you need only if delegate is != nil
- Add an invalidate method to QueueManager and call this method in the dealloc method of your UIViewController(s)

  > -(void)invalidate 
  >   {
  >       self->delegate = nil;
  >   }

in case you need a refresh on KVO: [Kvo programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Comment: +1 Second that. It makes "reconnecting" to the vc easier too, in case it will appear again and needs to respond to changes in the queue (and its contents).

Comment: Very interesting approach. It will make the QueueManager (that indeed exists) a fair bit more complex, but it will also make the delegation more robust. I'll let it marinate a bit but it sounds like the way to go.

Comment: If you need some sample code look in the FetchedImageLinker sample code from Apple documentation.  There is a class named WatchedOperationQueue (or something like that, dont have the doc here) that implements the described behaviour.

Comment: Couldn't find the sources, but I get the gist. One thing is new to me though, why would you use `self->delegate = nil` instead of just assigning nil via `self.delegate = nil`?

Comment: the difference between the two syntaxes is that with self->delegate you are directly accessing the ivar, self.delegate is just syntactic sugar that will call the setter setDelegate:

if you declare the delegate as assign and use the default accessor's implementation the two are the same

Comment: I added the final solution to the question, it was 90% of what you suggested @Guilano, thanks!

Comment: Hey Giuliano, thanks for the wonderful answer! I was having trouble finding the sample code package that you mentioned. Is there perhaps another name for that package?

Answer (score 0):

The best advice here is to review the architecture of the app to avoid such situations. However, if there current code can't be changed some-why, you can use **NSNotificationCenter**. Every time your view controller is deallocated you can post a notification, this notifications must be caught by the **NSOperationQueue** holder, simple foreach cycle in the notification handler to **nil** the delegate for a deallocated view controller. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be checking to ensure that any delegates, if non-nil, are also able to respond to a message from the operation completion.  You do this using the `respondsToSelector` function that all NSObject subclasses posess.

In my projects, I've abstracted this checking into a category on NSObject that lets me safely call delegates with an arbitrary number of object arguments:

`- (void) dispatchSelector:(SEL)selector 
           target:(id)target 
          objects:(NSArray*)objects 
     onMainThread:(BOOL)onMainThread {`

if(target && [target respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    // Do your delegate calls here as you please
  }
}

You can see the full example here: https://github.com/chaione/ChaiOneUtils/blob/master/Categories/NSObject-Dispatch.m

Comment: If everything is done properly, a protocol should be in place anyway to which the delegate conforms...

Comment: Not an answer to my question, though I'll just let you know that all the delegate protocols are in place and have required methods only. Thus no checking needed.